# ¿Cómo crear un trigger que elimina si un item no cumple una condicion?

Tags: sql-server, trigger, delete

He creado un trigger que se ejecuta despues de una actualización en la `tablacabecera`. Luego de la actualización el trigger lo que hace es, seleccionar los códigos de productos con la descripción `promo` y la cantidad que haya ingresado en la tabla detalle deber ser mayor a 12.

Por ejemplo un producto que tenga la `descripcion`=*promo* y la cantidad ingresada en el `detalle`<*13*, el código de producto debe ser eliminado de  `tabladetalle`. Si el código de producto corresponde a la `promo` y la `cantidad`>*13* entonces el trigger modifica la `tablacabecera` con la descripción de promo válida.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[triggerprueba]

ON  [dbo].[tablacabecera]
AFTER UPDATE
AS 

BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

--SE DECLARAN VARIABLES
DECLARE @totalRegistros INT = (SELECT COUNT(CODPRESUPUESTO) FROM inserted)

DECLARE @registroactual INT = 1;

DECLARE @registros TABLE (iterator INT IDENTITY(1,1),codpresupuesto INT);

DECLARE @PROMO13  INT, @RESULTADO13 DECIMAL(18,2);


-- RELLENA LA TABLA TEMPORAL
INSERT INTO @registros
SELECT codpresupuesto FROM inserted



-- COMPRUEBA LA CANTIDAD DE REGISTROS
IF @totalRegistros>0
BEGIN TRY
    -- RECORRE LOS REGISTROS
    WHILE @registroactual<=@totalRegistros
    BEGIN
        -- VERIFICA SI EL PEDIDO ES UNO MODIFICADO PARA INGRESAR A POSCOMM
        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted I INNER JOIN @registros R ON R.codpresupuesto=I.CODPRESUPUESTO WHERE R.iterator=@registroactual AND TRANSFERIDO IS NULL)

        BEGIN
            --OBTIENE EL CODPRESUPUESTO DEL REGISTRO ACTUAL
            DECLARE @CODPRESUPUESTO INT = (SELECT I.CODPRESUPUESTO FROM inserted I INNER JOIN @registros R ON R.codpresupuesto=I.CODPRESUPUESTO WHERE R.iterator=@registroactual);

            DECLARE @CODPRODUCTO INT = (select  d.CODPRODUCTO AS codigo  from tabladetalle d, PRODUCTOS P where  P.CODRUBRO in(190,205) and P.DESPRODUCTO LIKE  'PROMO%'  and P.CODPRODUCTO=d.CODPRODUCTO and d.CANTIDAD <=12  and CODPRESUPUESTO= @CODPRESUPUESTO);


           --Obtiene el codigo del producto en promocion y la cantidad si es menor a doce
            IF  EXISTS(select   d.CODPRODUCTO AS codigo  from tabladetalle d, PRODUCTOS P where  P.CODRUBRO in(190,205) and P.DESPRODUCTO LIKE  'PROMO%'  and P.CODPRODUCTO=d.CODPRODUCTO and d.CANTIDAD <=12  and CODPRESUPUESTO= @CODPRESUPUESTO)

               

            SET @PROMO13 = 0
            ELSE
             ---se obtiene el codigo del producto en promocion y en caso de que la cantidad de mayor a doce la promocion es valida
                IF  EXISTS(select  d.CODPRODUCTO as codigo   from tabladetalle d, PRODUCTOS P where  P.CODRUBRO in(190,205) and P.DESPRODUCTO LIKE  'PROMO%'  and P.CODPRODUCTO=d.CODPRODUCTO and d.CANTIDAD >12  and CODPRESUPUESTO= @CODPRESUPUESTO)
            SET @PROMO13 = 1

            BEGIN

             
            IF @PROMO13 = 0
             --elimina el producto que no tiene la cantidad valida para la promo  
            delete p from dbo.tabladetalle p join inserted d on d.CODPRESUPUESTO = p.CODPRESUPUESTO and CODPRODUCTO=@CODPRODUCTO;
           

                --UPDATE tablaprueba SET  DIRENVIO='RETENIDO POR PROMO INVALIDA', TRANSFERIDO='P',OBSERVACIONES='RETENIDO POR PROMO INVALIDA'  WHERE CODPRESUPUESTO=@CODPRESUPUESTO

                
              else if @PROMO13 = 1
        
              UPDATE tablaprueba SET OBSERVACIONES='PROMOCION VALIDA', PORCENTAJEDESCUENTO=10 WHERE CODPRESUPUESTO=@CODPRESUPUESTO
              
                END
        END
        --PASA AL SIGUIENTE REGISTRO
        SET @registroactual=@registroactual+1;
    END
END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    -- ENVIA CORREO CON ERROR
    DECLARE @error NVARCHAR(MAX) = ERROR_MESSAGE();
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='Alertas DB',
    @recipients= 'correo@gmail.com',
    @subject=  'Error',
    @body= @error
END CATCH

END
```

Los productos que están seleccionados en la tabla corresponden a la promo en este caso deberia eliminarse los productos con el código *3334* y *4230* y los productos con el codigo *3330* y *3331* entrarían en la promocion mientras que los productos que no estan marcados y no corresponden a la categoria de promo segiran en la tabla sin que se ejecute el trigger.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al ejecutar el trigger me lanza este error.

Msg 3930, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_send_dbmail, Line 64 [Batch Start Line 0]
La transacción actual no se puede confirmar ni admite operaciones que escriban en el archivo de registro. Revierta la transacción.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personalmente no me gustan nada los triggers que utilizan iteraciones para resolver algo que se puede hacer perfectamente desde conjuntos.

Porque lo que estás haciendo no es más que una `update` **relacionando cabeceras, detalles y productos** con un predicado `where`.

Y un `delete` de la misma manera, y no tienes que hacer nada más.

Pero primero lo que tienes.

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.triggerprueba ON dbo.tablacabecera
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRAN;
            SET NOCOUNT ON;
        
            --SE DECLARAN VARIABLES
            DECLARE @TotalRegistros INT = (
                                        SELECT Count(CODPRESUPUESTO)
                                               FROM inserted
                                      );
            DECLARE @Registroactual INT = 1;
            DECLARE @Registros TABLE
                                 (
                                 iterator       INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
                               , codpresupuesto INT
                                 );
            DECLARE @PROMO13     INT;

        -- RELLENA LA TABLA TEMPORAL
            INSERT INTO @Registros
            SELECT codpresupuesto
                   FROM inserted;

            -- COMPRUEBA LA CANTIDAD DE REGISTROS
            IF @TotalRegistros > 0
            BEGIN
    
            -- RECORRE LOS REGISTROS
                WHILE @Registroactual <= @TotalRegistros
                BEGIN
                    -- VERIFICA SI EL PEDIDO ES UNO MODIFICADO PARA INGRESAR A POSCOMM
                    IF EXISTS (
                                SELECT 1
                                       FROM inserted AS I
                                            INNER JOIN @Registros AS R ON R.codpresupuesto = I.CODPRESUPUESTO
                                       WHERE
                                            R.iterator = @Registroactual AND TRANSFERIDO IS NULL
                              )
                    BEGIN
                        --OBTIENE EL CODPRESUPUESTO DEL REGISTRO ACTUAL
                        DECLARE @CODPRESUPUESTO INT = (
                                                        SELECT r.CODPRESUPUESTO -- YA LO TIENES EN LA TABLA TEMPORAL
                                                               FROM @Registros AS R 
                                                               WHERE R.iterator = @Registroactual
                                                      );
                        DECLARE @CANTIDAD INT;
                        DECLARE @CODPRODUCTO INT;
                        /* PUEDES LEER AMBOS DATOS A LA VEZ. UNA CONDICIÓN OBLIGATORIA ES QUE SOLO HAYA UNA LINEA POR CODPRODUCTO EN EL DETALLE. */
                        select @CODPRODUCTO=D.CODPRODUCTO, @CANTIDAD = d.cantidad
                                from tabladetalle AS d
                                   , PRODUCTOS AS P
                                where
                                     P.CODRUBRO in (190, 205) 
                                    and P.DESPRODUCTO LIKE 'PROMO%' 
                                    and P.CODPRODUCTO = d.CODPRODUCTO 
                                    and CODPRESUPUESTO = @CODPRESUPUESTO
                        

                        --Obtiene el codigo del producto en promocion y la cantidad si es menor a doce
                        IF @CODPRODUCTO IS NOT NULL And @CANTIDAD IS NOT NULL AND @CANTIDAD <13
                        BEGIN
                            SET @PROMO13 = 0;
                        END
                        ELSE
                        BEGIN
                            ---se obtiene el codigo del producto en promocion y en caso de que la cantidad de mayor a doce la promocion es valida
                            IF @CODPRODUCTO IS NOT NULL And @CANTIDAD IS NOT NULL AND @CANTIDAD > 12
                            BEGIN
                                SET @PROMO13 = 1
                            END;
                        END;
                    
                        IF @PROMO13 = 0
                        BEGIN
                            --elimina el producto que no tiene la cantidad valida para la promo  
                            delete p
                                   from dbo.tabladetalle p
                                        WHERE p.CODPRESUPUESTO=@CODPRESUPUESTO --ya lo tienes leido en la variable.
                                        and CODPRODUCTO = @CODPRODUCTO;

                            --UPDATE tablaprueba SET  DIRENVIO='RETENIDO POR PROMO INVALIDA', TRANSFERIDO='P',OBSERVACIONES='RETENIDO POR PROMO INVALIDA'  WHERE CODPRESUPUESTO=@CODPRESUPUESTO
                        END
                        else
                        BEGIN
                            if @PROMO13 = 1
                            BEGIN
                                UPDATE tablaprueba
                                       SET OBSERVACIONES = 'PROMOCION VALIDA'
                                         , PORCENTAJEDESCUENTO = 10
                                WHERE CODPRESUPUESTO = @CODPRESUPUESTO
                            END;
                        END;
                    
                    END;
                    --PASA AL SIGUIENTE REGISTRO
                    SET @Registroactual =
                           @Registroactual + 1;
            END;
            END;
            COMMIT TRAN;
            END TRY
            BEGIN CATCH
            -- ENVIA CORREO CON ERROR
                IF @@TRANCOUNT>0 
                    ROLLBACK TRAN;

                DECLARE @Error NVARCHAR(MAX) = Error_Message();
                EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @Profile_name = 'Alertas DB'
                                       , @Recipients = 'correo@gmail.com'
                                       , @Subject = 'Error'
                                       , @Body = @Error;
            END CATCH
    END;
```

Hay pocos cambios en el código. Eliminar lecturas repetidas varias veces. Y poner y quitar End que yo diría que estaban un poco enrevesados.

La sintaxis de unir las tablas en el `Where` ya está muy obsoleta. Deberías de usar `On`.

Además de los errores de concepto que para mi tiene el trigger y que deberías de abordar.
Imáginate que hay una update, dentro de un tiempo que tiene que cambiar 10.000 tablaCabecera y hay que hacer una update, porque se ha añadido una columna, y hay que hacerlo mediante un bucle. Se dispara el trigger las 10.000 y sale mal.

**Envías 10.000 correos**. Eso no parece lógico.

Poner un envió de emails, en un catch, creo que es algo voy a decir, **"extraño"**

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.triggerprueba ON dbo.tablacabecera
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRAN;
            SET NOCOUNT ON;
                
                delete p
                       from dbo.tabladetalle p join inserted i on p.codPresupuesto = i.codPresupuesto
                                join PRODUCTOS P ON P.CODPRODUCTO=d.CODPRODUCTO 
                                
                                where  P.CODRUBRO in(190,205) and P.DESPRODUCTO LIKE  'PROMO%'  
                                        and 
                                       d.CANTIDAD <=12 ;


            COMMIT TRAN;
            END TRY
            BEGIN CATCH
            -- ENVIA CORREO CON ERROR
                IF @@TRANCOUNT>0 
                    ROLLBACK TRAN;

                DECLARE @Error NVARCHAR(MAX) = Error_Message();
                EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @Profile_name = 'Alertas DB'
                                       , @Recipients = 'correo@gmail.com'
                                       , @Subject = 'Error'
                                       , @Body = @Error;
            END CATCH
    END;
```

**Nota:** la sentencia `update` no te la pongo, porque tablaPrueba, debería de tener un codProducto, para que tuviera sentido, ya que 2 filas bien y una mal, serían dos updates y un delete.

Como no has puesto un escenario reproducible con datos, este es el máximo acercamiento que te puedo dar.

Comment: Gracias   Javi fer2 ahora he probado y fumciona, le he quitado lo del correo